# To identify the relation between two sets in a linear transformation(mcq)

Tags: linear-transformations

If $T:R^{n}\to R^{n}$ is a linear transformation $(n\ge 2)$.Then for $k\le n$,if $E=${$v_1,..,v_k$}$\subseteq R^{n}$ and $F=${$Tv_1,..,Tv_k$}.Then what is true?

a)if E is L.I. then F is L.I.

b)if E is L.I. then F is L.D.

c)if F is L.I. then E is L.I.

d)if F is L.I. then E is L.D.

I have used L.I. for linearly independent and L.D. for linearly dependent.

I think first two need not be true as we don't know what T is.But can't think about last two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No. Take $T=0$.
2. Nope. Take $T=id$.
3. Yes. Suppose $E$ is L.D., then you can make some $v_j$ from other $v_i$'s and by linearity we have that $Tv_j$ can be made from the other $Tv_i$'s, which is a contradiction.
4. Nein. Take $T=id$, then $T^{-1}=id$, so if $F$ is L.I., then $E=F$ is also L.I.

Comment: Thanks$\ddot\smile$.